# Fixed footer if content is lesser than window height, relative footer if content is greater than window height, with ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have tried to fix this problem for ages!
When loading content with ajax dynamically, how can i guarentee that my footer is fixed to the bottom, if my loaded content is lesser than the window height, and vice versa, if my content is greater than the window height, it will simply be relative, and follow the content div as normal.

My current code, which works on most setups, but on certain small laptops, it simply does not work as i expect.

```
if ($('main').height() >= $(window).height() || $(document).height() >= $(window).height()) {
    $('.footer').removeAttr('style');
    $('.footer').css('position', 'relative');
} else {
    $('.footer').removeAttr('style');
    $('.footer').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('.footer').css('bottom', '0');
}
```

Any ideas? It should be so simple. So i feel like i'm missing something.

Comment: try to use min-height. Get window height and set it to .main, with position relative.

Comment: Ok, will test, thanks!